# How to present a UIViewController with an bottom-up animation without hiding TabBar

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbar, modalviewcontroller

So, i have a `UITabbarController` with an `UINavigationController` in it. On the press of a button, i would like to bring in another `UINavigationController`, animating it like when using `presentModalViewController:animated:`, but i do not want it to hide the TabBar.

Is there anything in UIKit (3.1.3 and later) that i could use for this or will i have to do the animating myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just test the code, maybe you need to set the `navigationController` as `property` if you need do sth like `pushViewController:animated:`.

```
UIViewController * aViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[aViewController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
[aViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aViewController];
[aViewController release];
[navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
[navigationController release];
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way by default to present something from the bottom up is the presentModalViewController. You can actually override the animations for your navigationController, but it isn't something you can achieve just by calling a different method, you will have to create your own, and handle the animations too.

Another way to possibly cheat this would be to reload your tabBar in the view you are presenting modally, but that could get messy.

Comment: hm :/ i'd like to do it via a navigation controller, but it seems like it is not possible to push one navigatiocontroller onto another

Comment: You can load a navigation controller inside a modal view controller. That happens all the time and is pretty easy to do.

Comment: Yeah, but i can't use a modal view controller, because a modal view controller is meant to block interaction with all other UI an thus hides the UITabBar.

Comment: This isn't meant to be a dig, but it might be worth rethinking your UI. Users are used to certain types of navigation. What you are proposing goes against the norm and could confuse users as well as make your navigation (and development) spaghetti like. Hope you figure it out.